v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle() Cannot create a handle without a HandleScope with NAPI plugin and workerpool
We have a REST web service written in TypeScript that runs on Node, and a large legacy C++ library that provides services for the web service. We use NAPI to provide JS bindings for the C++ library, basically it's a NAPI plugin. This has worked well now for several years.
We have recently added support for timeouts in the REST service (calls to the C++ library can be very slow for complex data). To do this we use the workerpool package which allows us to do the actual work in a Node worker thread. Our NAPI plugin is now being called from the worker thread.
Mostly this works perfectly, however we have found a single situation where we get this error and stack from our service:
FATAL ERROR: v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle() Cannot create a handle without a HandleScope
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0xb80b5c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]
 2: 0xeedd86 v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x1093f52 v8::internal::HandleScope::Extend(v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]
 4: 0xeef668 v8::EscapableHandleScope::EscapableHandleScope(v8::Isolate*) [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]
 5: 0xc5ba9a napi_open_escapable_handle_scope [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x7ffff7c6065a Napi::Value NapiHelpers::CreateWrapperInstance<RedactedObjectNodeWrapper>(std::initializer_list<napi_value__*> const&) [/workspaces/Redacted-Web/node_modules/@redacted/Redactedsdk-node/dist/linux/Redactedsdk.node]
 7: 0x7ffff7c60b2c Napi::Array NapiHelpers::CreateArrayOfWrappers<RedactedObjectNodeWrapper, RedactedSDK::RedactedObject>(Napi::CallbackInfo const&, std::vector<RedactedSDK::RedactedObject, std::allocator<RedactedSDK::RedactedObject> > const&) [/workspaces/Redacted-Web/node_modules/@redacted/Redactedsdk-node/dist/linux/Redactedsdk.node]
 8: 0x7ffff7c5afbb  [/workspaces/Redacted-Web/node_modules/@redacted/Redactedsdk-node/dist/linux/Redactedsdk.node]
 9: 0x7ffff7c400d4 Napi::Value NapiHelpers::WithNapiScope<Napi::Value>(Napi::CallbackInfo const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::function<Napi::Value ()>) [/workspaces/Redacted-Web/node_modules/@redacted/Redactedsdk-node/dist/linux/Redactedsdk.node]
10: 0x7ffff7c5a448 DrawingNodeWrapper::GetRedactedObjects(Napi::CallbackInfo const&) [/workspaces/Redacted-Web/node_modules/@redacted/Redactedsdk-node/dist/linux/Redactedsdk.node]
11: 0x7ffff7c5e506 Napi::InstanceWrap<DrawingNodeWrapper>::InstanceMethodCallbackWrapper(napi_env__*, napi_callback_info__*) [/workspaces/Redacted-Web/node_modules/@redacted/Redactedsdk-node/dist/linux/Redactedsdk.node]
12: 0xc4f059  [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]
13: 0xf565df v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo) [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]
14: 0xf56e4d  [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]
15: 0xf57315 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]
16: 0x1961df6  [/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v20.15.0/bin/node]

----- JavaScript stack trace -----

1: unstringifyRedactedObject (/workspaces/Redacted-Web/applications/Redacted-web-service/dist/RedactedObjectFactory.js:76:20)
2: calculateProperties (/workspaces/Redacted-Web/applications/Redacted-web-service/dist/workers/PropertyCalculatorWorkers.js:18:52)
3: /workspaces/Redacted-Web/node_modules/workerpool/src/worker.js:150:27
4: [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:820:20)
5: node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28

Our C++ library is thread safe (we lock a global mutex at every entry point), and this has been used in multi-threaded C++ and C# applications.
NapiHelpers::WithNapiScope creates a HandleScope:
template<class T>
T NapiHelpers::WithNapiScope(
    const Napi::CallbackInfo& info,
    const std::string& unknownErrorMessage,
    std::function<T()> callback)
{
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();
    Napi::HandleScope scope(env);

    try
    {
        return callback();
    }
    catch (const ChemDrawSDK::Exception& e)
    {
        Napi::Error error = Napi::Error::New(info.Env(), e.what());
        error.Value().DefineProperty(Napi::PropertyDescriptor::Value("code", Napi::Number::New(info.Env(), e.GetErrorCode()), napi_default));
        throw error;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        throw Napi::Error::New(env, e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        throw Napi::Error::New(env, unknownErrorMessage);
    }
}

Later on in the stack though, the HandleScope is no longer valid. This feels like a reentrancy problem (where some other thread has changed the handle scope), however I would expect to see this problem a lot more than we have if that was the case.
Does anyone know what is happening here? In particular is it possible to safely call a NAPI plugin from a Node worker thread like this? Is there anything we need to do to isolate handle scopes to a particular thread?

A properly written Node-API addon should work from multiple isolates. The trick is to never use global variables. All the persistent data must be stored in per-isolate data structures. When being loaded from a worker_thread your addon will be initialized separately for each thread. I guess that your addon is storing data in global variables. Maybe the env is not the same env as the one Node.js called you with.
Thus said, you have found an incredibly complex way to manage async C++ calling. node-addon-api has an AsyncWorker.
